# Grid layout issue

Tags: wpf, layout, grid

I have the following xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox Width="120" Text="Search" Margin="10"/>
        <Button>Search</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In both the designer and the running application the right edge of the button is cut off, but only if the textbox has a margin on the right side.  How do I create separation between the two without cutting off the buttton.  Is this a bug?

Edit:
The StackPanel is in Column 1 not Column 0. Additionally, the button border reappears after the button has been clicked.  Window size is 525 and the grid is the only thing in it.

Comment: Doesn't cut off for me, unless the outermost Grid's width is 360 pixels or less. Seems an odd way to do layout, though -- a variable-width column with fixed-width content.

Comment: @JoeWhite That's odd.  My grid has no set width (window width of 525).  The column doesn't just have that in it... this is just a simplified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your first ColumnDefintion's Width to Auto

I'm guessing that since the width is not defined, it's making them both `*`, which means they'll be of an equal width. By setting the 1st to `Auto` you're telling it to take up however much space it needs, then letting the 2nd column fill the remaining space.

Comment: Ugh... basic mistake.  Thanks!

Comment: @mydogisbox lol no problem, I make those kinds of mistakes almost daily :)

Comment: Hmmm, while this fixed my problem, I'm not really sure if it addresses why there was a problem to begin with.  Buttons don't have a pre-defined with, so it should have just filled the available space (assuming the available space was non-zero, which it was).

Comment: @mydogisbox If the columns are both `*` width, it means they will be of equal size. The button was likely getting clipped because it did not fit into the column, which was set to half the size of the Grid. As a simple check, set the Grid's background color to something and I think you will see that the column was exactly half the Grid's width.

Comment: @mydogisbox RE: your edit, it's because the `((Grid Width) - 1stColumnWidth) / #ofStarColumns)` is not large enough for your `TextBox + Margin + Button`. In other words, `((525 - 150) / 2)` is less than `(150 + 10 + 10 + buttonWidth)`. Setting the 2nd column's width to `Auto` should still fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a bug- the combination of the 120px of width (of the text box) + the width of the button when it's contents is the string "Search" (whatever that may be) + the 150px of the first column is wider than whatever is the space allocated by the container of the Grid.

What did you expect to happen?  Scrollbars?

Comment: The stack panel is in column 1 not column 0.